# Understanding “solltest du Fragen haben”

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase

I got the following e-mail from my teacher:

> Hallo,
>
> hier die Korrektur, solltest du Fragen haben, können wir am Donnerstag darüber sprechen.
>
> Schönen Tag und bis morgen!

I fail to understand “solltest du Fragen haben”. I understood it like I should ask her, but Google translate translates it to something like: “if you have any questions”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> solltest du Fragen haben

is a common german expression. Google is right in translating it to

> if you have any questions

The full translation would be:

> Here is the correction. If you have any questions, we can talk about them on thursday.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know maybe why "Du solltest Fragen haben" is "You should have questions"  and why example from mail has different meaning? Maybe should I not understand it but only memorize?

Comment: "Solltest" can here be replaced by "falls", "sofern", "wenn". That's a possibility to check this phrasing. Also, if somebody wants to tell you to ask questions, they say something like "überleg dir Fragen, wir reden dann drüber".

Comment: It's the tricky part about the german question.
(I have to admit I am not good at explaining german grammar, I just know how to use it, but I'll try anyway).
`Solltest du Fragen haben` is a special  structure (i forgot the name, sorry). `Solltest` is basically the same as 'if' in this structure.
`Du solltest Fragen haben` on the other hand is derived from the 'Konjunktiv II' structure. The 'Konjunktiv II' is used in different scenarios. 1) Wishes and/or requests e.g. 'I _wish_ I _would_ be able to fly' -> 'Ich _wünschte_ ich könnte fliegen'

Comment: 2) Sentences talking about consequences of things that aren't happening e.g 'if you _would give_ me that ball i would give you 10 dollars' -> 'Wenn du mir den Ball _geben würdest_, würde ich dir 10 Dollar geben'. And finally 3) "suggestions" e.g 'You _should have_ questions' -> 'Du _solltest_ Fragen _haben_' . In that case the teacher thinks that you should have questions (that it is likely to have questions) , in german it is formulated like a suggestion. Think of 'You shouldn't drink poision' , which is also an implicit suggestion.

Comment: @PiotrDróżdż Just want to add that it's exactly the same in English. She could have said "We can talk on Thursday should you have any questions", and I believe the meaning would be the same.

Answer (score 4):

@Erik Lohmann, @mindbomber: Es ist nicht so, dass 'solltest' mit 'wenn' oder 'falls' gleichzusetzen ist, es hat auch nichts bzw. nicht so viel mit dem Konjunktiv 2 zu tun. Die hier gewählte Konstruktion nennt sich Verb-Erstsatz. Verb-Erstsätze gibt es im Deutschen bei

- Ja/nein-Fragen: *Kommst du?*
- Imperativen: *Komm mir bloß nicht wieder mit dieser alten Geschichte!*
- Konditionalsätzen: *Kommst du noch mal so spät, gibt's Ärger!*

Der entscheidende Punkt ist das Verb am Satzanfang. Man kann Konditionalität durch *wenn*- oder *falls*-Nebensätze, durch 'konditionale Adverbialgruppen' (*im Falle* + Genitiv oder *im Falle von* + Dativ, *in Notfällen, bei Bedarf*...) oder Adverbien (*bedarfsweise, notfalls* ...) oder eben durch Verb-Erstsätze bezeichnen.

Sehr viele dieser Verb-Erstsätze werden mit '*sollte/st/t/n*' eingeleitet: *Sollte sich das als wahr herausstellen, ...* Der entsprechende Satz im Indikativ ohne 'sollte' hat einen stärker temporalen Charakter: *Stellt sich das als wahr heraus, dann müssen wir uns eine andere Strategie überlegen.* (≈ ab dem Zeitpunkt, wo / sobald sich das als wahr herausstellt ...). Mit 'sollte' ist dieser Satz hypothetischer. Möglicherweise handelt es sich hier um dieselbe Art von 'sollte', die auch eine von der Vergangenheit aus gesehenen unbestimmten Zukunft bezeichnet, welche inzwischen aber real eingetreten ist: *Die These Galileos sollte sich später als zutreffend herausstellen.* Oder: *In den 20er Jahren ging sie nach Moskau. Dort sollte sie ihren späteren Ehemann kennenlernen.*

Comment: It is correct that 'solltest' does not replace a *wenn*. Actually the sentence also works without *solltest*: **Hast du Fragen, können wir am Donnerstag darüber sprechen.** Not as common as the sentence with *solltest*, but completely correct.

Comment: Natürlich ersetzt ein solltest nicht ein wenn oder falls, es hat aber in diesem Kontext die gleiche Funktion. Mehr habe ich auch nicht geschrieben. Die Erwähnung des Konjunktiv II bezog sich auf "Du solltest Fragen haben", welches meines Wissens nach sehr wohl ein Satz im Konjunktiv II ist. Den Namen 'Verb-Erstsatz' hab ich noch nie gehört, aber schön dass jemand das Wort dafür kennt.

Comment: Ich hatte deutlich machen wollen, dass es nicht das 'solltest' ist, das diese 'wenn-Funktion' trägt, sondern die Stellung des Verbs am Kopf des Nebensatzes. Das 'solltest' hat demgegenüber eine temporale/modale Bedeutung, die ebenfalls eine Eventualität beinhalten kann, aber es scheint mir keine konditionale, sondern eine  andere Art von Eventualität zu sein, wie bei vielen Modalverben im Konjunktiv 2: 'Das dürfte / müsste eigentlich / könnte / sollte wohl genügen.' Vgl. auch 'das sollte mich wundern', konditionalisiert zu 'sollte dich das wundern, dann lies ältere Texte, da gibt es das oft'.

Answer (score 0):

There can be this same structure in German, in English and in French:

- Deutsch: "Solltest du Fragen haben, können wir..."
- English: "Should you have any questions, we can..."
- French: "Devrais-tu avoir des questions, nous pouvons..." (although this French structure is now considered outdated).